# Can't receive from USB bulk endpoint despite Windows enumerates and libusb reads descriptor of STM32 custom device class

Tags: stm32, libusb, winusb

For a fast ADC sampling USB device, I am using the USB 2.0 High Speed capable STM32F733 with the embedded USB-HS PHY. In USBView, I can see that the device is enumerated, the libusb code opens the device and claims interface, but **when I try to receive data with libusb_bulk_transfer, the operation times out** (return code -12). Things I have tried: I have confirmed than when I request data with libusb_bulk_transfer, the device is interrupted. Note: I have DMA enabled in my class configuration C file and it is not clear to me how that is triggered. I have verified that the transfersize and packet count registers are being set correctly by the LL library function, and that when I request data from

Any tips on debugging such problems will be much appreciated - this board is my undergrad thesis due in under two months!

Desktop sequence:
`libusb_get_device_list, libusb_get_device_descriptor, libusb_open, libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii, libusb_free_device_list, libusb_bulk_transfer(devh, fat_EPIN_ADDR, inframe, fat_EPIN_SIZE, &gotBytes, 100)`. Where gotBytes is integer, and inframe is a large array.

Device firmware:

```c
MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();
uint8_t txBuffer[10*fat_EPIN_SIZE];
while (1)
{
  USBD_LL_Transmit(&hUsbDeviceHS, Custom_fat_EPIN_ADDR, txBuffer, Custom_fat_EPIN_SIZE);
  HAL_Delay(1);
}
```

Custom_fat_EPIN_SIZE is 0x200 and the endpoint address is 0x81 (EP IN 1)
Installed driver for device is WinUSB (verified in Device Manger to be winusb.sys), and I am linking libusb-1.0 into my desktop program. You can find my source code at https://gitlab.com/tywonemi-school-stuff/silicon-radar-fun, the firmware is My SW/v1 and the desktop software is a Qt Creator project in My SW/Viewer, of note is usb.cpp. You can also compare with testing project/HIDTest, which is code that I tested with STM32F303 nucleo dev board where I was able to read an array through IN bulk endpoint with the Viewer application. However, F3 has the USB peripheral, while F7 has OTG_USB, and I am now attempting USB 2.0 compliant HS so there may be more protocol-based pitfalls. You can also find the output of the device descriptor etc from USBView in my SW/USBView_broken.txt

EDIT 1: I have found finally some concrete error in the STM32 behavior. The DMAADDR is set for EPIN 0x81, and never increments, despite the DMA being enabled. I have went through literally every occurrence of the word "DMA" in the USB_OTG periphery.

I thought it might be that my linker script makes my array be stored in DTCM or similar, and the OTG DMA can't access it, but the address of txBuffer is 0x2003EBEC which is in SRAM2. The AHB matrix in the reference manual clearly shows, that the USB OTG HS DMA is master for a bus that SRAM2 is a slave of. And DTCM is connected too. I will look for application notes for USB OTG HS DMA - it just seems to be refusing to copy data!

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed my issue by disabling the DMA setting. I have re-read the relevant portions of the reference manual and still don't know how exactly the values propagate into the Tx FIFOs. It is possible that DMA-less operation will be a major bottleneck in my project, I might return to this later.